# Как записать массив байтов в PNG файл?

Tags: изображения, файлы, java, png

Есть массив типа `byte[]`. Пусть он будет наполнен случайными числами. Как записать его в PNG-файл, который будет именно PNG (его можно будет открыть как картинку), а потом оттуда вытащить?

---

Пробовал делать `BufferedImage`, но исходный массив из него не получается .

Comment: можно BMP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061029/how-to-make-bmp-image-from-pixel-byte-array-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В своё время использовал вот такую либу для работы с png "Sixlegs Java PNG Library" чисто как декодер, а вот эта может и кодировать в png [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/)

Comment: в принципе у java sdk нет кодера/декодора png обычного, есть только свинговский класс ImageView и всё

Comment: @shkiper, а можно поподробней про PNGJ, а то вроде массив получилось запихать в PNG, а вытаскивается уже совсем другой.

Comment: А, нет, все, спасибо, разобрался, не правильно просто по массиву проходил.